# left join linq is not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

i have this linq query

```
var x = (from d in detalle
from n in nlj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join nd in nuevodetalle
on new { d.ope_idsku ,d.ope_tipo } equals new {nd.ope_idsku ,nd.ope_tipo }into nlj
from n in nlj.DefaultIfEmpty()


select new { d, n } ).ToList();
```

now if i do it

```
x[0].d==null this return false
x[0].n==null this return false
x[1].d==null this return false
x[1].n==null this fails, why?
```

my real select is not {d,n } it is

```
select new ope_detalle_autoventa()
{
CreatedOn = d.CreatedOn,
ModifiedOn = d.ModifiedOn,
ope_autoventaid = d.ope_autoventaid,
ope_Codope = d.ope_Codope,
ope_detalle_autoventaId = (tiene_nuevo_primarykey) ? Guid.NewGuid() : d.ope_detalle_autoventaId,
ope_entregado = (d.ope_entregado - (n != null ? n.ope_entregado : 0)),
ope_envase = d.ope_envase,
ope_estado = d.ope_estado,
ope_icono = d.ope_icono,
ope_idsku = d.ope_idsku,
ope_name = d.ope_name,
ope_pedido = d.ope_pedido,
ope_precioV = d.ope_precioV,
ope_prestamo = d.ope_prestamo,
ope_promocion = d.ope_promocion,
ope_skuid = d.ope_skuid,
ope_tipo = d.ope_tipo,
ope_autoventaidTarget = d.ope_autoventaidTarget,
ope_skuidTarget = d.ope_skuidTarget,
Ope_NumVenta = d.Ope_NumVenta,
ope_descuento = d.ope_descuento,
ope_cancelado = d.ope_cancelado,
ope_folio = d.ope_folio,
ope_cantcanc = 0,
ope_estimado = "0"
}
```

but this get fails same reason `x[1].n==null` fails, (that i believe),
i believe this fails at this line

```
ope_entregado = (d.ope_entregado - (n != null ? n.ope_entregado : 0)),
```

however
this query doesn't fail

```
var restaragregados = (from r in resultadoregresar
group new { r.ope_entregado } by new { r.ope_idsku } into agrupacion
select new { agrupacion.Key.ope_idsku, entregadototal=(agrupacion.Sum (x=> x.ope_entregado) ) }
);
List<ope_detalle_autoventa> nuevodetalle = (from d in detalle
join c in cargainventario
on d.ope_idsku equals c.ope_idsku into clj
from c in clj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join r in restaragregados on
d.ope_idsku equals r.ope_idsku into rlj
from r in rlj.DefaultIfEmpty ()
where (c!=null?c.ope_carga == cargausada:c==null  )
&& (d.ope_entregado > ((c==null ?0:c.ope_disponibles ) - (r==null?0:r.entregadototal)))
&& d.ope_tipo ==tipos[i]
select new ope_detalle_autoventa()
{
ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,
ope_autoventaid = ope_autoventaid,
ope_detalle_autoventaId = d.ope_detalle_autoventaId,
ope_entregado = (d.ope_entregado - ((c== null ? 0 : c.ope_disponibles) - (r == null ? 0 : r.entregadototal))),
ope_envase = d.ope_envase,
ope_estado = d.ope_estado,
ope_icono = d.ope_icono,
ope_idsku = d.ope_idsku,
ope_name = d.ope_name,
ope_pedido = 0,//0 por que no pidio de esta carga sino de la que ya se gastó
ope_precioV = d.ope_precioV,
ope_prestamo = d.ope_prestamo,
ope_promocion = d.ope_promocion,
ope_skuid = d.ope_skuid,
ope_tipo = d.ope_tipo,
ope_autoventaidTarget = d.ope_autoventaidTarget,
ope_skuidTarget = d.ope_skuidTarget,
Ope_NumVenta = d.Ope_NumVenta,
ope_descuento = d.ope_descuento,
ope_cancelado =d.ope_cancelado ,
CreatedOn =DateTime.Now ,
ope_Codope =d.ope_Codope ,
ope_folio =d.ope_folio,
ope_cantcanc =0,
ope_estimado="0"
}
).ToList();
```

i rename n by c  and i change

```
on new { d.ope_idsku ,d.ope_tipo } equals new {nd.ope_idsku ,nd.ope_tipo }into nlj
by d.ope_idsku equals nd.ope_idsku into nlj
```

but i get the same error.

[image]

Comment: move your code a little bit more to right. I can still see some characters.

Comment: Thanks - it would have been better to leave some indent though for readability, just not enough that most of the code is scrolled-off horizontally.

Comment: I think the problem is that the two anonymous objects new { d.ope_idsku ,d.ope_tipo } and new {nd.ope_idsku ,nd.ope_tipo } will never be equal since the default Equal-method will compare references rather than content.

Comment: I'll try using d.ope_idsku equals nd.ope_idsku and using a where for add d.ope_tipo=nd.ope_tipo, and i'll say you

Comment: @Casperah i changed but yet i get the same error

Comment: @Casperah the problem was in DefaultIfEmpty() i changed it with DefaultIfEmpty(otherobject)

Comment: @Casperah The `Equals` method of anonymous objects is overridden to do a memberwise comparison of all of the properties of the object, not to compare references specifically so that you *can* do exactly this.  In any case though, it's using a query provider, not linq to objects, so it's not going to invoke `Equals` anyway.

Comment: +1 for clarifying Equal method of anonymous objects and that it is not used in linq for sql. Thank you, I learned two things today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this

```
 if (nuevodetalle.Count == 0)
                nuevodetalle.Add(detalle [0]);
            ope_detalle_autoventa clone = (ope_detalle_autoventa)detalle[0].Clone();
            clone.ope_idsku = 0;
            clone.ope_entregado = 0;
            clone.ope_tipo = 0;
            List<ope_detalle_autoventa> detallecargaactual = new List<ope_detalle_autoventa>();


            var x = (
                from d in detalle
                join c in nuevodetalle
                //on new { d.ope_idsku, d.ope_tipo } equals new { c.ope_idsku, c.ope_tipo } into clj
                on d.ope_idsku equals c.ope_idsku into clj
                from c in clj.DefaultIfEmpty (clone)
                select new{ d, c}).ToList();`enter code here
```

you can see i changed  `clj.DefaultIfEmpty (clone)`